# Im currently trying to put the entry box next to the label at the bottom of the GUI. for player 1 and 2. How can i solve this problem?

Tags: python, tkinter

#Libary#
from tkinter import *

#Frame Window display window#

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Tic Tac Toe Start Window')
#root.iconbitmap('Images/tic_tac_toe.ico')
root.geometry('830x700')
root.configure(bg="#FFC300")
```

#Players label, Entry box Here can the players enter there name#
#player 1#

```
L1=Label(text='Enter your name player 1: ', font=14)
L1.place(relx=0.0, rely=1.0, anchor='sw')
L1.configure(bg='#FFC300')
    
E1=Entry(root, font=14)
E1.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor='w')
E1.configure(bg='#FFC300')
```

#player 2 here can player 2 enter there name#

```
L2=Label(text='Enter your name player 2: ', font=14)
L2.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor='se')
L2.configure(bg='#FFC300')
    
E2=Entry(root, font=14)
E2.grid(row=0, column=3)
E2.configure(bg='#FFC300')
```

#Mainloop#

```
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mixing `.grid()` and `.place()` isn't actually forbidden, but it's unlikely to ever result in a usable layout.  The problem is that the gridded widget has no knowledge about the placed widgets, so you have no control over where it appears in relationship to them.  Using `.grid()` for everything (or `.pack()`, where appropriate) is likely to give better results.  (In all my years of using Tkinter, I can only recall one instance where `.place()` was actually required.)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @jasonharper, the choice of the layout management functions used in the code, can make a difference. Here using `grid` to manage the entire layout is better to achieve the desired results(as mentioned in the OP), than to mix it up with the `place` geometry manager.

The reason using `grid` is a better option here compared to place is as grid can be used to easily define the rows and columns which allow you to render one widget below the other. `place` on the other hand can be more effective in use cases wherein a widget has to exactly be rendered at certain coordinates on the screen.([this](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/layout-mgt.html) might be helpful)

This means changing the lines that currently use `place` to use `grid` instead, the rows and columns can be adjusted as per need but provided below is an ideal sample of what it might look like -:

```
# IMPORT STATEMENTS
from tkinter import *

## INITIALIZING ROOT
#Frame Window display window#
root = Tk()
root.title('Tic Tac Toe Start Window')
#root.iconbitmap('Images/tic_tac_toe.ico')
root.geometry('830x700')
root.configure(bg="#FFC300")

## DEFINING THE WIDGETS
#Players label, Entry box Here can the players enter there name# #player 1#
L1=Label(text='Enter your name player 1: ', font=14)
    
E1=Entry(root, font=14)

#player 2 here can player 2 enter there name#
L2=Label(text='Enter your name player 2: ', font=14)
    
E2=Entry(root, font=14)

## LAYOUT MANAGEMENT(USING GRID FOR ALL)(THOSE LINE'S COMMENTED ARE THE ONE'S PREVIOUSLY USED AND NOW REPLACED.)
# L1.place(relx=0.0, rely=1.0, anchor='sw')
L1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
# E1.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor='w')
E1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
# L2.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor='se')
L2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
# E2.grid(row = 0, column = 3) # REPLACED WITH APPROPRIATE GRID STATEMENT FOR THE IDEAL SAMPLE
E2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

# CONFIGURING WIDGET BACKGROUNDS.
L1.configure(bg='#FFC300')
E1.configure(bg='#FFC300')
L2.configure(bg='#FFC300')
E2.configure(bg='#FFC300')

#Mainloop#
root.mainloop()
```

This gives the desired output as -:
[image: OUTPUT WINDOW]

Answer (score 0):

It is more easier to put those labels and entries inside a frame and then put the frame at the bottom of the window.

```py
import tkinter as tk

BG = '#FFC300'
FONT = 'Arial 14'

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Tic Tac Toe Start Window')
root.geometry('830x700')
root.configure(bg=BG)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=BG)
frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

L1 = tk.Label(frame, text='Player 1:', font=FONT, bg=BG)
E1 = tk.Entry(frame, font=FONT, bg=BG)

L2 = tk.Label(frame, text='Player 2:', font=FONT, bg=BG)
E2 = tk.Entry(frame, font=FONT, bg=BG)

L1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
E1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

E2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
L2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```